# Python ValueError: time data '2001-11-03 ' %Y:%m %d %H:%M:%S' when dates in csv file are month/day/year

Tags: python, pandas, csv, datetime, datetime-format

I'm having an issue where the date format is not matching up. Meaning in my .csv file the dates are as follows **%m/%d/%Y** (ex. 11/3/2001) but in the error it saying **%Y/%m/%d** or **%Y/%d/%m**. I've tried all the possible permutations as far as year, month and day and I continue to recieve the same error of **ValueError: time data '2001-11-03 ' %Y:%m %d %H:%M:%S'**. Below is my code. Thanks.

```
   df = pd.read_excel('.xlsx', header=None)
   df.to_csv('.csv', header=None, index=False)
   df= pd.read_csv('.csv', index_col[5,8,9,12], date_parser=lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y/%m/$d %H:%M:%S').strptime('%m/%d/%Y))
```

Note: What I'm trying to do is convert an .xlsx file to .csv and then remove the trailing 0:00 from multiple columns within the .csv file. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `parse` from `dateutil.parser` to parse the date appropriately. It is an easy access. The fastest way to parse dates.

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv', date_parser = parse, index_..)
```

our you can use `to_datetime` native to Pandas

```
pd.to_datetime(df['Date Col'])
```

In order to format the date properly, you should use the following:

```
date_parser=lambda x: parse(x)
#parse from dateutil.parser
df['Date Col'] = df['Date Col'].strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
df.to_csv('New File.csv')
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. When incorporating your idea: ***df = pd.read_csv('.csv', date_parser=parse, index_col=[5...])*** it does not remove the 0:00 at the end like I was trying to do. Is there something I'm missing? I'm new to this so maybe. Here is my original code: ***df= pd.read_csv('.csv', index_col[5,8,9,12], date_parser=lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y/%m/$d %H:%M:%S').strptime('%m/%d/%Y))*** Thanks. @iDrwish

Comment: `strptime` is to transform date from string to a `datetime` object, `strftime` transform datetime to `str`. You should do: `date_parser= lambda x: parse(x).strftime('%m/%d/%Y')`.

Comment: Hello, that seems to work with a minor tweak, but with your suggestion, I now have an error of ***ValueError: unconverted data remains 0:00*** and when adding the %H:%M to the code the error goes away, but the 0:00 remains in my .csv file which I am trying to remove ha. Any suggestions? Thanks @iDrwish

Comment: I am not sure how to handle this in the parsing process. You can always parse the file, edit it, and save it again. Check the edit.

Comment: It's quite a large file to do that, but thank you for helping me with my question. I truly appreciate it @iDrwish

Answer (score 0):

You can use `to_datetime` since you are using pandas. [**MoreInfo**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html)

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"a": ["11/3/2001", '2001-11-03']})
df["a"]  = pd.to_datetime(df["a"])
print(df["a"])
```

**Output:**

```
0   2001-11-03
1   2001-11-03
Name: a, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```